# PHP to csv exportation error

Tags: php, csv, export

I have a problem with my code. When I fill the PHP form and submit on the page, I encounter with 2 problems;

1- It writes all 6 input coming from 6 textareas to next line in csv file as I want. But it writes all of them into the 1st cell of row I want it to write to 6 different cells of course.
2- After submitting the form, if you press backspace the form is opened again with the previous input in textareas, I want them to be empty. I'd appreciate if you help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this should be useful for you: http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm

Answer (score 0):

you have to give more information of how you write your csv files as well as which program tries to open them.

in regard to going back to the last page: that behavior comes from your browser -> better add a button / link in the submit page to add a new entry

Comment: I open them with Excel 2007. I created an xls file and converted it into a csv file by a tool

Comment: ok, how does your csv file look like?
"col1";"col2";"col3" or entierly different?

You say you save it with a tool - aren't you doing that in php? or is this a separate problem?